# Need to get text from html using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm stuck, can't get data needed, this is the html code

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="final-results">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 instruction">
            <h4>Final and Return</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 non-printable">
            <img class="img-responsive rotate-card" src= "...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
            <div class="data-box">
                <div class="name">Final Ending</div>
                <div class="value">123456789</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
            <div class="data-box">
                <div class="name">Available Phase</div>
                <div class="value">250</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
            <div class="data-box">
                <div class="name">Initial Phase</div>
                <div class="value">500</div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Here's my python code :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(form_resp.content, features="html.parser")

    avail_phase = soup.find("div", text="Available Phase").find_parent("div", class_="value").text

    initial_phase = soup.find("div", text="Initial phase").find_parent("div", class_="value").text

    logger.info("Success! Final Number: {}".format(avail_phase))

    return {"initial_phase": initial_phase, "available_phase": avail_phase}
```

I'm getting the same error no matter what i do "Last error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'"

Seek your help please

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to scrape data from the line `class='value'`, then you may use `find_next_sibling`, for I see the `class='value'` is a sibling of the text you are searching for initially (`Available Phase` and `Initial Phase`)

I must tell you that I am providing this solution on the basis of just looking at the code as I don't think I have a way to test this at present. So, try this code and find out if it works.

```
avail_phase = soup.find("div", text="Available Phase").find_next_sibling("div", class_="value").text


initial_phase = soup.find("div", text="Initial phase").find_next_sibling("div", class_="value").text
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

1. You try to select the parent with `find_parent("div", class_="value")`, but there is no parent tag with this criterias.
2. Your selection `soup.find("div", text="Initial phase")` won't find a tag, cause it needs an exact match of `Initial phase`

#### How to fix?

1. Change to `.find_next("div", class_="value").text` or `.find_next("div").text` or `.find_next_sibling("div").text` to get the text of the next `<div>`
2. Change `text="Initial phase"` to `text="Initial Phase"` to find the right `<div>`

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="col-xs-12 instruction">
            <h4>Final and Return</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 non-printable">
            <img class="img-responsive rotate-card" src= "...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
            <div class="data-box">
                <div class="name">Final Ending</div>
                <div class="value">123456789</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
            <div class="data-box">
                <div class="name">Available Phase</div>
                <div class="value">250</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
            <div class="data-box">
                <div class="name">Initial Phase</div>
                <div class="value">500</div>
            </div>

        </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

avail_phase = soup.find("div", text="Available Phase").find_next("div", class_="value").text
initial_phase = soup.find("div", text="Initial Phase").find_next("div", class_="value").text

print({"initial_phase": initial_phase, "available_phase": avail_phase})
```

#### Output

```
{'initial_phase': '500', 'available_phase': '250'}
```

Comment: Your solution works, the problem why i'm getting the error because i'm not landing on the right page so those values aren't found that's what trigger  the error "'NoneType' object"
Thank you for your help